# grep -f: printing pattern line numbers

Tags: grep

I'm using `grep -f patternfile inputfile` and I want to output the line numbers from the pattern file. For example, if `patternfile` is

```
abc
def
```

and `inputfile` is

```
abcx
abcy
defx
```

I want something like

```
1 abcx
1 abcy
2 defx
```

where 1 corresponds to the fact that abcx and abcy are matched from Line 1 of `patternfile`, and 2 corresponds to the fact that defx is matched from line 2 of `patternfile`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`. Content of `script.awk`:

```
FNR == NR {
        pattern[ FNR ] = $1;
        next;
}

FNR < NR {
        if ( FNR == 1 ) {
                l = length( pattern );
        }
        for ( i = 1; i <= l; i++ ) {
                if ( $0 ~ pattern[i] ) {
                        printf "%d %s\n", i, $0;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk patternfile inputfile
```

With following output:

```
1 abcx
1 abcy
2 defx
```